# PROMPT_COMMAND duplicating commands on new sessions

Tags: linux, bash, logging

Im playing around with PROMPT_COMMAND variable
Was testing out some ways to save all commands into a log file and got some ways using PROMPT_COMMAND + logger + rsyslog

Example export im using

> export PROMPT_COMMAND='logger -p local6.debug "$(whoami): $(history 1 | sed "s/^[ ]*[0-9]+[ ]*//" ) "'

Its working fine, but I notice that everytime I login in a new session, ssh / sudo / etc... it will log the last entrance on history (from old sessions) again on the logs

After checking some doc I get that PROMPT_COMMAND will execute always before bash show prompt, and it means even on your first session prompt when you logging into your system

Wonder if someone already notice it, and if there are some way to avoid it from logging on when login new session on bash